# Content from TSV file into a Multi-Deimensional Array

Tags: c, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I have been given a TSV file. 
I am reading through it using a getchar() function and I enter program < testfile.tsv into my command line when running my function.

```
    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
```

I am able to read through it but i dont know how to store the strings in a multidimensional array. How to make an array that would be A[ROW][COLUMN]?

Sample Input(\t is tab, \n is newline):

Anything\tIs\tPossible\tYay\n

What\tDo\tI\tDo\n

This\tis\tgreat\twow\n

This is what I tried doing.

```
    if (c == '\t') {
        columncount += 1;
        A[rowcount][columncount] = c;

    };
    if (c == '\n') {
        columncount += 1;
        A[rowcount][columncount] = c;
        rowcount += 1;
        columncount = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Just to nitpick, even whe you use tab instead of comma to separate the fields, the term to use is still [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Comment: I think it's fine to call it a TSV file. The wiki page about CSV linked above mentions that using CSV as a label for both formats "can cause problems in data exchange." When I use tab-separated files, they often share a folder with comma-separated files, and it's very helpful to know which one I'm dealing with by looking at the file extension or talking about it as TSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple: When you read a tab you increase the index variable used for column, and when you read a newline you reset the column index and increase the line index variable.

You should make sure that the index variables are properly initialized before you start reading, and that you don't go out of bounds when incrementing the variables.

Also don't forget to terminate the strings when you get a tab or newline. Don't put the tab or newline character in the strings.

Finally, you need an array of arrays *of arrays*, i.e.

```
char A[ROWS][COLUMNS][MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRINGS];
```

Translated into code, you could do something like

```
int c;
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
int string_index = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c == '\t')
    {
        A[row][column++][string_index] = '\0' // Terminate the string
        string_index = 0;
    }
    else if (c == '\n')
    {
        A[row++][column][string_index] = '\0' // Terminate the string
        string_index = 0;
        column = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (string_index >= MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRINGS)
        {
            printf("Error: String to long at row %d, column %d\n", row, column);
            break;
        }
        if (row >= ROW)
        {
            printf("Error: row is to large: %d\n", row);
            break;
        }
        if (column >= COLUMN)
        {
            printf("Error: column is to large: %d (at row %d)\n", column ,row);
            break;
        }

        A[row][column][string_index++] = c;
    }
}
```

Now to do something with the loaded texts, how about printing it?

```
for (row = 0; row < ROW; ++row)
{
    for (column = 0; column < COLUMN; ++column)
    {
        printf("A[%d][%d] = %s\n", row, column, A[row][column]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do I make the array equal to, to store the string

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if you could walk me through this. How do I form the string for the Array when getchar() reads 1 character at a time. I dont have much experience with C.